# Why do users need 200+ reputation on a SE site to get a combined flair?

Tags: feature-request

For new users who are just starting out with Stack Exchange, and who are on multiple sites, having a combined flair would really help them promote their Stack Exchange account. However, you need at least one account with at least 200+ reputation, which is a bit of a tall order for a new user. To make it easier on new users, why doesn't the flair show the Stack Exchange sites with the most reputation, instead of showing the Stack Exchange sites where the user has 200+ reputation on?

Thoughts? Questions? Comments?

Comment: Patience, Grasshopper

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that I have accounts on over 25 stack exchange accounts, almost all of them with 101 rep, and fitting that many on a flair would be... pointless?

Comment: The moment you reach 200 reputation, you're considered an avid user with the added bonus of [reduced ads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads).  At that point, it shows that you are likely to be a long-term user of the site.  You should only have user flair listing sites you've participated enough in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It is not called *A piece of valuable flair* by chance.

The 200 points rep is also the threshold for the 100 point bonus when cross registering on other SE sites. You then need only 100 rep points at each new domain to reach inclusion in the combined flair.

As others have said before, your better interest is to focus on the site you can do the most good (asking, **answering**, **voting**, commenting), then look around.

Answer (score 9):

If I had an account with less than 200 reputation, it would mean I haven't participated much, and am therefore unworthy of such a prestigious honor.

### Suggestions

- Focus on one site.
- Remember this?

  > **Obi-Wan:** He [Luke Skywalker] will learn **patience**.
  >
  > **Yoda:** Much anger in him, **like his father**.

  You don't want to be Anakin, do you?

Comment: Wait, so, is the lesson "don't wish for user flair too quickly, or your son might be destined to save the galaxy from your wrath, but along the way also be tempted by user flair"?

Comment: @Renesis Pretty much. (Except that I'll kill my son before saying "*I am your father!*")

Comment: I do want to be Anakin, he who was killed by a traitorious Jedi.

Answer (score 4):

Thoughts- those interested in Flair will quickly gain 200+ reputation before you can blink...

I'm presuming that the idea of displaying Flair (on your blog or wherever) is that you are saying that you are a user of this system and that it means something to you...e.g

> "I'm proud of what I have achieved on
>   these Sites"

Caring about this means you care about the system, and it'll seriously take you little time at all to get the reputation.